# How to use copy function in Vector?

Tags: c++, mfc, visual-c++

I want to copy collection of structures from one vector to another vector in mfc.

My Vector Structure is

```
     typedef  vector<CLog *> CLogData;

     typedef vector<CLog * > tLogData;
```

how to copy the TYPE CLog* from CLogData to tLogData?

Regards,

Karthik

Comment: Is there something in the docs for `vector` that is confusing you?

Comment: Do you mean you need to copy the objects that the pointers refer to? And is there a reason for storing pointers, rather than objects, in the vector?

Comment: Why do you have two identical `typedef`s here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a shallow copy of the `CLog*` pointers, use the answer MacGucky gave. If you need a deep copy of the actual data the `CLog*` pointers point to, you need to do it manually in a loop:

```
CLogData cl;
tLogData tl;
// fill cl
for(size_t i = 0; i < cl.size(); ++i){
  // invokes the copy ctor of CLog
  CLog* plog = new CLog(*cl[i]);
  tl.push_back(plog);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To copy one vector to another you can use `std::copy` in two ways:

1) resize target-vector and copy by iterator:

```
tlogData.clear();
tlogData.resize(CLogData.size());
std::copy(CLogData.begin(), CLogData.end(), tLogData.begin());
```

2) use an back_inserter:

```
std::copy(CLogData.begin(), CLogData.end(), std::back_inserter(tLogData));
```

But that copys only the pointers from one vector to another - the pointers direct to the same objects in both vectors!

---

If you want to really copy the objects, you have to create new ones:

```
size_t n = CLogData.size();
for (size_t i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
   tLogData.push_back(new CLog(*CLogData[i]));
}
```

This works only if `CLog` has an copy-constructor.

Comment: I did like these.but it will throw runtimeerror                        it will point to vector.h  and the error line is                         _SCL_SECURE_VALIDATE_RANGE(
   _Myptr + _Off <= ((_Myvec *)(this->_Getmycont()))->_Mylast &&
   _Myptr + _Off >= ((_Myvec *)(this->_Getmycont()))->_Myfirst);

Comment: You need to use the `back_inserter` iterator for `copy` unless you resize the destination container first.

Comment: Yes, sorry I forgot the back_inserter. I corrected my example and added both ways.

Answer (score 1):

Both types are the same. So you can just do

```
CLogData cl;
tLogData tl;
// todo: fill cl

tl = cl;
```

Comment: @Karthik - this is not Java! ;)

Comment: @Nim I'm moderately sure that the OP wants a full deep copy even though pointers are being stored in the container.

Comment: @Mark, me too, my comment was purely in relation to his comment! :)